# How can I extract the list of redirect titles from MediaWiki::API in Perl?

Tags: perl, mediawiki-api, hash-of-hashes

I'm trying to use the MediaWiki API to get all redirects from a certain Wikipedia title and I think i'm almost there but I get lost in the complex data structure of hashes and arrays.

How can I extract the list of redirect titles?

In the example I query for 'Japan' and should get a list that looks like this:

```
'JPN',"Land der aufgehenden Sonne","Das Land der aufgehenden 
Sonne","Zipango","\x{65e5}\x{672c}","R\x{ec}b\x{11b}n"
```

(a side question: Why do I not get UTF-8 strings for all cases? )

The code below is adapted from [MediaWiki::API](https://metacpan.org/pod/MediaWiki::API) documentation.

```
use MediaWiki::API;
use warnings;
binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';
use JSON;
use Data::Dumper;

my $LANG="de";

my $mw = MediaWiki::API->new( { api_url => 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php' }  );
my $mw_LANG = MediaWiki::API->new( { api_url => "https://$LANG.wikipedia.org/w/api.php" }  );

my $wikititle ="Japan";

my $alltitles = $mw_LANG->api( {
 action => 'query',
 titles => $wikititle,
 prop => 'redirects',
 format => 'json',
} )
|| die $mw_LANG->{error}->{code} . ': ' . $mw_LANG->{error}->{details};

#just print to know how the structure looks like
print Dumper($alltitles);

my ($pageid,$langlinks) = each ( %{ $alltitles->{query}->{pages} } );
print "pageid $pageid\n";#yes works:  this prints the page id
```

problem: how to get the actual titles in the `redirect-array`?

```
  my $relinks = $alltitles->{'query'}->{'pages'}->{$pageid}->{'redirects'}; #no does not work!

  foreach my $el ( @{ $relinks->{'title'} } ) {
    print " $el $el->{'*'}\n";
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query returns a hashref. One of the entries in this structure is `query` which points to another hashref which contains `pages`. The `pages` hashref contains keys which are page ids. Each of these point to another hashref which contains a redirects entry which is a reference to an array containing all the pages to which this page redirects.

Putting all those together:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use open qw(:std :utf8);

use MediaWiki::API;
use JSON::MaybeXS;
use Data::Dumper;

my $LANG= "de";

my $mw = MediaWiki::API->new( { api_url => 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php' }  );
my $mw_LANG = MediaWiki::API->new( { api_url => "https://$LANG.wikipedia.org/w/api.php" }  );

my $wikititle ="Japan";

my $alltitles = $mw_LANG->api( {
        action => 'query',
        titles => $wikititle,
        prop => 'redirects',
        format => 'json',
    }
) or die sprintf '%d: %s', @{ $mw_LANG->{error} }{qw(code details)};

for my $pageid ( keys %{ $alltitles->{query}{pages} } ) {
    my $r = $alltitles->{query}{pages}{$pageid};
    printf "Redirects for page %d with title '%s'\n", @{$r}{qw(pageid title)};
    for my $redirect ( @{ $r->{redirects} }) {
        printf "\t%d: '%s'\n", @{$redirect}{qw(pageid title)};
    }
}
```

[Postfix dereferencing](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2014/09/use-postfix-dereferencing/) makes things a bit cleaner:

```
for my $pageid ( keys $alltitles->{query}{pages}->%* ) {
    my $r = $alltitles->{query}{pages}{$pageid};
    printf "Redirects for page %d with title '%s'\n", $r->@{qw(pageid title)};
    for my $redirect ( $r->{redirects}->@* ) {
        printf "\t%d: '%s'\n", $redirect->@{qw(pageid title)};
    }
}
```

This requires `perl` 5.20 or later.

Comment: `$r->{redirects}->@*` what's going on with that? Is that similar to the perl6 version of `$_`? Isn't that going to require a specific minimum version of perl?